# Issues of injection surjection and bijection

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please let me know the issues of injection surjection and bijection. I wants the fully explanation or mathematical definition of it.

Also you can share me issues of injection surjection and bijection

Comment: Consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$.  The identity map $\iota: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a bijection.  The inclusion map $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ where $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is injective because each possible output corresponds to a unique input.  The map $g:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ where a given integer's parity determines its output is surjective because everything in the range of the function is a possible output of $g$.

Comment: Can you share me an example of the same ? with new response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a function $f:F\to F'$, then:

- Injective: $x\in F\ne x'\in F \to f(x)\ne f(x')$
- Surjective: $\exists x \operatorname{s.t.} y\in F' \to f(x)=y$
- Bijective: both of the above

Comment: Thanks Man. Its perfect it will be good if you will share me an theory as well thanks you much dude.

Comment: they're definitions - no theory involved

Comment: Fine thanks. Its good here with this.

Comment: @ni3 try the chat for broader discussion based type questions.